# JaVers gives incorrect result for the custom list diff

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, javers

I have a class Node and it has list of devices. For example

```
    class Node {
        String nodeCode;
        String name;
        List devices;
    }

    class Device {
        String deviceCode;
        String name;
    }
```

I am comparing two Node objects using LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE algorithm and scenarios are mentioned below :

**Senario - 1. Remove device1:**

```
 Old Version:
         var device1 = Device("d1", "device1")
         var device2 = Device("d2", "device2")
         var devices = mutableListOf<Device>()
         devices.add(device1)
         devices.add(device2)
         val before = Node("n1", "node1", devices)  // Old Version


 Current Version:
       var newDevice1 = Device("d1", "device1")
       var newDevices = mutableListOf<Device>()
       newDevices.add(newDevice1)
       var after = Node("n1", "node1", newDevices) // New Version

 Compare both version:
 var diff = javers.compare(before, after)
 println("$diff")

Output:

changes on com.example.audit.Node/ :
'devices' collection changes :
1. 'com.example.audit.Node/#devices/1' removed
```

**Senario - 2. Add device2:**

```
  Old Version:
       var newDevice1 = Device("d1", "device1")
       var newDevices = mutableListOf<Device>()
       newDevices.add(newDevice1)
       var after = Node("n1", "node1", newDevices) // Old Version

  Current Version:
       var device1 = Device("d1", "device1") 
       var device2 = Device("d2", "device2")
       var devices = mutableListOf<Device>()
       devices.add(device1)
       devices.add(device2)
       val after1 = Node("n1", "node1", devices)  // New Version

  Compare both version:
  var diff = javers.compare(after, after1)

Output:

changes on com.example.audit.Node/ :
'devices' collection changes :
1. 'com.example.audit.Node/#devices/1' added
```

**Senario - 3. Remove device1 from the position 0 in device list:**

```
  Old Version:
       var device1 = Device("d1", "device1") 
       var device2 = Device("d2", "device2")
       var devices = mutableListOf<Device>()
       devices.add(device1)
       devices.add(device2)
       val after1 = Node("n1", "node1", devices)  //Old Version

 Current Version:
      device2 = Device("d2", "device2") 
      var newDevices2 = mutableListOf<Device>()
      newDevices2.add(device2)
      val after2 = Node("n1", "node1", newDevices2) // New Version

    Compare both version:
    diff = javers.compare(after1, after2)

Output:

changes on com.example.audit.Node/ :
'devices' collection changes :
1. 'com.example.audit.Node/#devices/1' removed
```

3rd scenario is giving wrong output. I removed device1 from the 0th position in the list but it is giving removed from the 1st position in the device list.

I want 3rd scenario output like:

```
changes on com.example.audit.Node/ :
'devices' collection changes :
0. 'com.example.audit.Node/#devices/0' removed
```

Is JaVers having limitations for list of custom object?

I missed 3rd scenario in my prototype. I went and integrated into my project and changes are moved to stage. This is blocked me to release.

Can you provide your input what I have to make change to get expected result?

Comment: Why you are using non parameterized List? Its a bad practice since Java 7 and that's definitely not good for Javers. Javers won't guess that `List devices` is a list of Device, but simply will treat it as a List of Objects

Comment: The LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE algorithm should not consider indexes. but still it is considering indexes if you see my 3rd scenario output mentioned above.

Comment: I just gave example but i am using it List<Device> in my class

Comment: Push a runnable test case, like these https://github.com/javers/javers/tree/master/javers-core/src/test/groovy/org/javers/core/cases

Comment: Here my program -  https://github.com/shivusajjan/javers-example/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/RemoveElementFromMiddleOfListTest.java - @BartekWalacik

Comment: spock test https://github.com/shivusajjan/javers-example/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/example/CaseIndexChangeProblemForRemovedObjectFromList.groovy

Answer (score 0):

JaVers works fine, you are misusing `Value Objects`. Lists of Value Objects are not convenient to compare, because Value Objects (by definition) have no identity. You can get expected result when you map your objects inside lists as `Values`

(Groovy)

```
package org.javers.core.cases

import org.javers.core.JaversBuilder
import org.javers.core.diff.ListCompareAlgorithm
import org.javers.core.diff.changetype.container.ListChange
import org.javers.core.metamodel.annotation.Id
import org.javers.core.metamodel.annotation.TypeName
import spock.lang.Specification

import static java.util.Objects.equals

class shivusajjan extends Specification {

    @TypeName("Address")
    class Address {
        String city
        String street

        Address(String city, String street) {
            this.city = city
            this.street = street
        }

        @Override
        String toString() {
            return "Address{" +
                    "city='" + city + '\'' +
                    ", street='" + street + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    @TypeName("Employee")
    class EmployeeClass {
        @Id String name
        List<Address> addressList

        EmployeeClass(String name, List<Address> addressList) {
            this.name = name
            this.addressList = addressList
        }
    }

    def "should compare list of Values using LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE"() {
        given:
        def javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
                .withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE)
                .registerValue(
                        Address,
                        { a, b -> equals(a.city, b.city) && equals(a.street, b.street) },
                        {a -> a.toString() }
                )
                .build()

        def previousAddresses = [ new Address("Bangalore", "Vinayaka"),
                                  new Address("Bangalore", "Vijayanagar")]
        def previousEmp = new EmployeeClass("Frodo", previousAddresses)

        def currentAddresses = [ new Address("Bangalore", "Vijayanagar") ]
        def newEmp = new EmployeeClass("Frodo", currentAddresses)

        when:
        def diff = javers.compare(previousEmp, newEmp)

        then:
        println diff.prettyPrint()
        ListChange change = diff.getChangesByType(ListChange)[0]
        change.changes[0].index == 0
    }
}
```

output

```
Diff:
* changes on Employee/Frodo :
  - 'addressList' collection changes :
    0. 'Address{city='Bangalore', street='Vinayaka'}' removed
```

Comment: Can't we get output something like mentioned below?

`
changes on Employee/Frodo :
    -  'addressList' collection changes :
       0. 'Employee/#addressList/0' removed`
`